# Simplifying WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to simplify this WHERE statement so one only has to declare the Airport and StoreName once and let the category and fixture vary?

```
SELECT * FROM  Product_Display
WHERE (Airport = 'JFK' AND StoreName = 'T3' AND Category = 'Pralines' AND FIXTURE like '%W15%') 
OR (Airport = 'JFK' AND StoreName = 'T3' AND Category = 'Kinder' AND FIXTURE like '%W12%') 
OR (Airport = 'JFK' AND StoreName = 'T3' AND Category = 'Nutella' AND FIXTURE like '%G04%') 
OR (Airport = 'JFK' AND StoreName = 'T3' AND Category = 'Tic Tac' AND FIXTURE like '%W12%')
```

Comment: Yes, you can have Airport and StoreName conditions only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify like below

```
SELECT * FROM  Product_Display
WHERE Airport = 'JFK' AND StoreName = 'T3' AND ((Category = 'Pralines' AND FIXTURE like '%W15%') 
OR (Category = 'Kinder' AND FIXTURE like '%W12%') 
OR (Category = 'Nutella' AND FIXTURE like '%G04%') 
OR (Category = 'Tic Tac' AND FIXTURE like '%W12%'))
```

Hope this would help you out.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Product_Display
WHERE   Airport = 'JFK'
        AND StoreName = 'T3'
        AND ( ( Category = 'Pralines' AND FIXTURE LIKE '%W15%' )
              OR ( Category = 'Kinder' AND FIXTURE LIKE '%W12%' )
              OR ( Category = 'Nutella' AND FIXTURE LIKE '%G04%' )
              OR ( Category = 'Tic Tac' AND FIXTURE LIKE '%W12%' )
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query is semantically the same, but probably easier to read:

```sql
SELECT * FROM  Product_Display
WHERE (Airport = 'JFK' AND StoreName = 'T3') AND
  (    (Category = 'Pralines' AND FIXTURE like '%W15%') 
    OR (Category = 'Kinder' AND FIXTURE like '%W12%') 
    OR (Category = 'Nutella' AND FIXTURE like '%G04%') 
    OR (Category = 'Tic Tac' AND FIXTURE like '%W12%')
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the airport and storename out of brackets, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  Product_Display
WHERE Airport = 'JFK' AND StoreName = 'T3' AND 
(
    (Category = 'Pralines' AND FIXTURE like '%W15%') 
    OR (Category = 'Kinder' AND FIXTURE like '%W12%') 
    OR (Category = 'Nutella' AND FIXTURE like '%G04%') 
    OR (Category = 'Tic Tac' AND FIXTURE like '%W12%')
)
```